# Can't login to the newsland.com website

Tags: blocked-services

The [www.newsland.com](http://www.newsland.com) site blocks Tor connections (using another browsers, login is successful):

[image: Screenshot of newsland.com]

Pressing "Войти" ("Enter"), nothing happens.

What should I change in the Tor settings in order to login to this site (and others which also block Tor connections)?

Answer (score 1):

Click the NoScript button next to the Tor button (which is next to the back button on your browser) and choose "Allow scripts globally". Beware that this is not safe and not at all recommended.